How to remove 'Chapter X' in front of the Bibliography?
I'm using a report class document but when I print my Bibliography I receive it as 'Chapter 6' and then in the line below 'Bibliography' before stating the entries. How do I suppress the chapter name on top of the page?
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm,paperwidth=22cm,tmargin=25.4mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=38.1mm,rmargin=25.4mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% Add dots to the Chapter entries in the ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
%Remove Chapter numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% Show down to subsubsection
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{-20pt}% Just some value...
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{%
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed!}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{hyperref,xmpincl,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-reversed}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Change the name of the TOC from Contents to Table of Contents
\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {Table of Contents}
}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\interlinepenalty=10000}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
%format chapter heading distance from the top of the page
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
% Adjust Bibliography spacing between entries
\newlength{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.2\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
\newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
Some Text with a \citep{Something} citation.

\newpage 
\begingroup
    \setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
    \setstretch{1}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat-reversed}
    \bibliography{Mendeley_Export}
\endgroup

\end{document}


After amending your code to use an existing .bib and cite an actual entry, I still can't get it to compile without error. Can you please make sure it compiles? (\setstretch is not core LaTeX - you probably need setspace but you might be using something else.) When I provide the missing definition, it compiles, but BibTeX reports the style file plainnat-reversed.bst to be missing. If I switch to plainnat, it works but doesn't reproduce your issue. So the problem is due to code you've not shared.

I added my full code I have before \begin{document} now if that helps with the error. As for plainnat-reversed.bst file - I modified the traditional 'painnat.bst' file as I wanted the Last name of the author to be displayed first while keeping all the style choices of this style

Do you still have the problem with plainnat?  Then use that in your example.  Do you have the problem if you remove the \renewcommand\thebibliography?  Then do so.  In general, work your way through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/107497

I found the issue thanks to the comment of cfr.
The issue was in the following line
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

The numbib command seems to have added the Chapter X text. Once I removed that it now shows up with only the Bibliography name. While I don't know exactly why that's the case, it solves my question.

Have a look at the very second page of the documentation of the tocbibind package: nottoc = Disables the inclusion of the ToC / numbib = Number the Bibliography heading. LaTeX packages are usually very well documented, so many issues can be solved by studying the manuals.

@nplatis But why didn't I get that with the OP's code?

@cfr Maybe this line was not there in the original code? The OP writes that they completed the code. I just tried what is currently posted and it outputs the "Chapter" before the bibliography.

@nplatis You're right. The question didn't include the line when I looked at it.
